# Where is Class Diagram on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, class-diagram, code-map

I could not see below Class Diagrom button on VS2013. Was this option excluded from VS2013. Where is Class Diagram on Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

[image]

There is a Map Code button in VS2013 but as my understanding it is not working like Class Diagram. Actually I don't understand how it works.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a Class Diagram the same way you add any other new project item, i.e. right-click the project and select Add -> New Item.

Answer (score 4):

Also, right-click the project, then click **View Class Diagram**.